# unique columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns with same name and values in excel, how to keep unique column in pandas

I am doing below:

```python
## Update4: adding empty columns###
#### combined data many rows with single rows ###
### rename the columns and insert the empty columns##
### Lat Long change to 7 decimal place###

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import os

def process_excel():
    global df_2g_f
    global df_3g_f
    try:
        # Browse for the input Excel file
        input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])
        if not input_file_path:
            return

        # Load the input Excel file
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(input_file_path)
        output_folder = "C:/Verizon"
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        output_filename = f"Single_row_Data_{current_datetime}.xlsx"
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path)

        # Process the "2G Datafill" tab
        if "2G Datafill" in excel_file.sheet_names:
            df_2g = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="2G Datafill")
            columns_to_drop = ["CellName","Tech", "Cell ID", "Site Name", "longitude", "latitude", "LAC", "NCC", "BCC",
                               "BCCHNO", "DCHNO", "bsPwrBDec", "Band", "channelGroup", "LCR", "g31TgId",
                               "HSN", "MAIO", "ParentNode", "gsmSectorId"]
            df_2g.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
            df_2g.rename(columns={"configuredMaxTxPower": "2G_configuredMaxTxPower"}, inplace=True)
            df_2g_f = df_2g

            # Merge with the "3G Datafill" tab based on "Nominal" values
        if "3G Datafill" in excel_file.sheet_names:
            df_3g = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="3G Datafill")
            columns_to_drop = ["Tech", "Cell ID", "Site Name", "RAC", "LAC", "SAC", "primScramCode", "uarfcnDL",
                               "uarfcnUL", "cpichPower", "maxTxPower", "LCR", "URA", "ParentNode"]
            df_3g.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
            df_3g.rename(columns={"configuredMaxTxPower": "3G_configuredMaxTxPower"}, inplace=True)
            df_3g_f = df_3g
                # Merge the data frames based on "Nominal" values

                #df_combined = df_combined.rename(columns={'Nominal': 'Name'})

        frames = [df_2g_f, df_3g_f]
        df_combined = pd.concat(frames)
        df_combined['Nominal'] = df_combined['Nominal'] + '_BB2'
        out = (df_combined
                   .replace('', np.nan).set_index('Nominal').stack().to_frame(name='value')
                  .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount())
                   .set_index('n', append=True)
                   ['value']
                   .unstack(level=[-1, -2]).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
                   .droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
                )
        out = out.rename(columns={'Nominal': 'Name'})
        out.insert(1, 'Node Type', 'Baseband')
        out.insert(2, 'Sw Release', '22.Q2')
        out.insert(3, 'Parent Rnc', '')
        out.insert(4, 'Parent Bsc', '')
        out.insert(5, 'Parent Baseband', '')
        out.insert(6, 'Connected Profile', '')
        out.insert(7, '#Template', '')
        out.insert(8, 'networkManagedElementId', '')
        out .rename(columns = {'2G DefaultRouter': 'address_2G_Default', '2G IP Address': 'address_2G_IP','3G DefaultRouter':'address_3G_Default' , '3G IP Address': 'address_3G_IP', 'BSC Broker IP': 'bscBrokerIpAddress', 'CellName': 'nodeBLocalCellId'}, inplace = True)
        default_value = 0
        out['latitude'] = (out['latitude'].fillna(default_value) * 10**5).astype(int)
        out['longitude'] = (out['longitude'].fillna(default_value) * 10**6).astype(int)


        column_name = "2G_configuredMaxTxPower"
        column_counts = out.columns.astype(str).value_counts()

        print("column_counts are follow:", column_counts)
        if column_name in column_counts and column_counts[column_name] > 1:
            duplicate_columns = out.columns[out.columns.isin([column_name])].tolist()
            print("Duplicate columns are:", duplicate_columns)
            for duplicate_column in duplicate_columns[1:]:
                out = out.drop(columns=duplicate_column)

        out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Combined Data", index=False)

        writer.save()
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Data processing completed.")

    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


# Create the Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Excel Data Processor")
window.geometry("300x150")

# Create the "Process" button
btn_process = tk.Button(window, text="Process Excel", command=process_excel)
btn_process.pack(pady=10)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

but getting `error :2G_configuredMaxTxPower not found in axis`, when I am dropping the all columns it is getting dropped but when I am dropping number of desired duplicate columns it is not getting deleted

input:

```
--------- 2G_configuredMaxTxPower| 2G_configuredMaxTxPower|2G_configuredMaxTxPower|
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
 15000                  | 15000                  | 15000                 |
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
  15000                 | 15000                  | 15000                 |
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

desire output:

```
-------------------------+
 2G_configuredMaxTxPower |
-------------------------+
 15000                   |
-------------------------+
```

my output df:
[image]

`column_counts` are follow:

```
nodeBLocalCellId           6
address_3G_Default         6
rbsid                      6
fingerprint                6
iubId                      6
latitude                   6
address_3G_IP              6
longitude                  6
3G_configuredMaxTxPower    6
address_2G_Default         3
gsmSectorName              3
address_2G_IP              3
2G_configuredMaxTxPower    3
bscBrokerIpAddress         3
Sw Release                 1
Node Type                  1
Parent Bsc                 1
Connected Profile          1
Name                       1
#Template                  1
Parent Rnc                 1
Parent Baseband            1
networkManagedElementId    1
dtype: int64
```

Duplicate columns are:

```
['2G_configuredMaxTxPower', '2G_configuredMaxTxPower', '2G_configuredMaxTxPower']
```

Comment: Would you edit your question and show the output of `print(out)`, where `print(out)` is executed just before the code currently shown in the question?

Comment: Total columns ['address_2G_Default', 'address_2G_IP',  'address_3G_Default','gsmSectorName', 'rbsid', 'address_2G_Default', 'address_2G_IP',  'address_3G_Default','gsmSectorName', 'rbsid', 'address_2G_Default', 'address_2G_IP'], I have these columns but I need to remove the duplicate columns only"address_2G_Default" but keep one like there are total 3 so I need to drop 2 and keep 1, rest I need to keep same means no need to drop the duplicate of other columns

Comment: when I am applying the code it says "address_2G_Default" not in axis, but it is present the the out data frame

Comment: In your code, what is the output of `print(column_counts)`?

Comment: column_counts:-
nodeBLocalCellId-6
address_3G_Default-6
rbsid-6
fingerprint-6
iubId-6
latitude-6
address_3G_IP-6
longitude-6
3G_configuredMaxTxPower-6
address_2G_Default-3
gsmSectorName-3
address_2G_IP-3
2G_configuredMaxTxPower-3
bscBrokerIpAddress-3
Sw-Release-1
Node-Type-1
Parent-Bsc-1
Connected-Profile-1
Name-1
#Template-1
Parent-Rnc-1
Parent-Baseband-1
networkManagedElementId-1
dtype: int64

Comment: Please edit your question to show/add new information.  The comments have very limited formatting capability and make the information difficult to understand.  You should be able to just copy/paste the output of `print(column_counts)` into a code block.

Comment: I have put my complete code here now

Comment: no its not working, can you please see the code which I edited just now, I have attached my out dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [@CodeDifferent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76642494/1409374) (which is probably more typically useful), here's a way to eliminate only your specified column's duplicated repeats.

```python
column_name = "2G_configuredMaxTxPower"

out = out.iloc[:, ~np.logical_and(out.columns == column_name, out.columns.duplicated())]
```

Comment: thanks for the support, this is working fine, instead of paycheck.. lots of blessings..

Answer (score 1):

pandas allow you to have duplicate column name but when you call `df["col_name"]`, it will return multiple columns.

You can use positional index to avoid that since positions are always unique (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Assuming you want to keep only first column in case of duplicates:

```py
# A sample dataframe with duplicate columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), columns=["2G"] * 3 + ["3G"] * 2)

col_index = np.ravel(np.argwhere(~df.columns.duplicated()))
df.iloc[:, col_index].to_excel(...)
```

Comment: no its not working, can you please see the code which I edited just now,

Comment: no its not working, can you please see the code which I edited just now, I have attached my out dataframe

Comment: @PrashantSharma So, you want to keep some of the duplicated columns?

Comment: yes. I need to keep some duplicate columns and need to remote the duplicated of some columns but keep one column, I have specified the column name which I want to delete like" 2G_configuredMaxTxPower", here in my input file there are 3 columns for it, but I need only 1 column rest 2 want to be deleted.

Comment: @rickhg12hs if you wish to give me you email id I can send you my input file as well

Comment: @PrashantSharma  I only do that when there is a giant paycheck attached.  :-)   All the Stack Exchange sites are for everyone.

Comment: @rickhg12hs :) :)